# "Every day" and present continuous vs simple present

Tags: progressive-aspect, continuous-aspect, present-progressive, present-tense

- Every day I'm eating vegetables.
- I eat vegetables every day.

Can someone explain if there's a nuance in meaning of the two? If there's a better situation to use one than the other? (doesn't have to be the sample sentences)

Comment: So based on that time diagram would the nuance between the two be that the present continuous, eating every day, only applies to the present and short future and the habitual simple present, eat every day, can be applied to the longer future and past as well?

Comment: If you wish to contact a user directly you must precede the user's name with @. So if you wanted to comment on my comment you need to write @Mari-Lou A here. If instead you comment under my post, I will be automatically notified. (I hope that's clear)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that there's two parts to your question.

I'll first try to answer whether leading or ending the sentence with "every day" makes a difference:

Leading with "every day" first can sometimes be used in conversations to put further emphasis on the importance of the recurrence of an event. This really only works face-to-face and for phone conversations though. In writing it just looks awkward to do so.

Here's an example anyway:

> "This guy manages to annoy me every day!"

vs.

> "Every day this guy manages to annoy me!"

As previously stated it's a little difficult to highlight the difference in writing. However if you phrase it this way, and purposefully overstress the "every day"-part when saying it, it results in conveying that the recurrence is of bigger importance to you than the fact that the guy annoys you.

Regarding the tenses:

As far as I know you would only use the present continuous to either express that you're eating vegetables at this very moment or that you're planning to eat vegetables at some point in the future (e.g. "I am eating vegetables tomorrow").

In your case, simple present is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> Every day I **do** the cooking

The verb *do* is used in the present tense. The present simple is normally used to express daily routines, actions and habits which are repeatable in the present and in the future. The simple present is often accompanied with frequency adverbs such as: *usually, often, sometimes, hardly ever* and *never*. For example,

> I never **do** the cooking, my partner **does**.

The present participle i.e., *doing*, with the time expression *every day* is possible in the following scenario:

> I'**m doing** the cooking every day
>   Every day I'**m doing** the cooking

The time expression *every day* has the same meaning as the frequency adverb *always*. It matters little where *every day* is positioned in the phrase, it can either begin or end the clause. Instead of *always*, other words with similar meanings (e.g., *forever*, *constantly*, and *continually*) can be used.

> I'm `always` doing the cooking
>   I'm `continually` doing the cooking

In all four examples the speaker can be expressing their irritation at having to perform a daily or oft repeated  duty/chore. This type of construction expresses annoyance in the *present*. If you are simply stating a fact then use the *simple present* instead.

> I `always` do the cooking
>   I do the cooking `every day`

If you want to express **future intent**, use a different time expression such as:

> Tomorrow/this week/on Saturday I'm doing the cooking.